# Does model check data or presenter do it?

Tags: mvp

I have question about MVP. If presenter sends request to model for data. Does model check these data or does presenter have to do it? For example: are data ok etc. Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple approaches you can take to validate your data: Either the Domain objects or a Service.

You model is your domain. In domain driven development, your domain should know how to validate itself. So, you might have a standard Validate method on either class in the model. That can get a little tricky, though, if you need to make a database call to do the validation, although you could require the relevant data to be passed to your validation method, or provide a delegate to get the data if it's necessary.

Alternatively, you could put all the validation in the Service later, which your presenter would be calling to retrieve and to persist the model. This would result in the so-called antipattern "anemic domain". But, if that fits your application and architecture best, it might be the correct choice.

I would caution against having the presenter do it. That's not really it's job and it does not get reused like the model and service.